# How do I call another contract's function in solidity and also specify amount of ether to send?

Tags: solidity, calldata

I want to call another contract's function when I call a function in my contract and send my msg.value to the other function. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
function execute(address _target, bytes[] memory _payload) {
    _target.call(_payload, value = msg.value);
```

How do I send the msg.value of the execute() function to _target in the .call() function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use that contract interface to execute the function easily. To send ETH the function must be payable.
Eg

```
interface Target {
  function someFunction() external payable;
}

contract MainContract {
  Target public target;

  constructor(address _tragetAddress) {
    target = Target(_targetAddress);
  }
  
  function execute() public {
    uint256 ethAmountToSend = address(this).balance;
    target.someFunction{value:ethAmountToSend}();
  }

}
```

Here `target.someFunction{value:ethAmountToSend}()` will send ETH to the target contract.